# How to read current table row input box using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to select the current row `<td>` tag input value, when check box is selected for that particular row, but it returns `null`.

I've tried to fetch the current row and I got it to read the value of input box of the selected checkbox row

```js
var allVals = [];
$('input[name=selectedBilties]:checked').each(function() {
   var  freight_id = $(this).closest('tr').find( $('input[name="freight_id[]"]') ).val();
   allVals.push($(this).val());
   allVals.push(freight_id);
});
console.log("All Values"+ allVals);
```

html table with `php->codeigniter`

```html
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;  ">
   <thead class="bg-info">
      <tr>
         <th>Select</th>
         <th>Bilty No</th>
         <th>Bilty Date</th>
         <th>Pkgs</th>
         <th>weight</th>
         <th>From</th>
         <th>TO</th>
         <th>Consignor</th>              
         <th>Consignee</th>
         <th>Remark</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody class="table-hover">
      <?php foreach($crossing as $pod){?>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="selectedBilties" name="selectedBilties" value="<?php echo $pod->id;?>"></td>
         <td><?php echo $pod->id;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $pod->lr_date;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $pod->no_of_pkgs;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $pod->lr_actual_weight;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $pod->lr_from;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $pod->lr_to;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $pod->consignor_name;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $pod->consignee_name;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $pod->lr_description;?></td>
         <input class="selected" type="text" id="freight_id" name="freight_id[]" value="<?php echo $pod->fr_memo_ids; ?>">
         <input class="selected" type="hidden" id="challan_id" name="challan_id[]" value="<?php echo $pod->challan_id; ?>">
      </tr>
      <?php }?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How is your HTML looks like? what are the issues you are facing?

Comment: @Mamun hey look at question I have updated it

Comment: How the sample output (array) should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the input elements inside *td*, otherwise the selector will not work. Also you have to execute your code on changing the check box as there is no check box checked initially:

```js
$('input[name=selectedBilties]').click(function(){
  var allVals  = [];
  $('input[name=selectedBilties]:checked').each(function() {
    
    var  freight_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="freight_id[]"]').val();
    var temp = [];
    temp.push($(this).val());
    temp.push(freight_id);
    allVals.push(temp);
  });
  console.log(allVals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;  ">
  <thead class="bg-info">
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Bilty No</th>
      <th>Bilty Date</th>
      <th>Pkgs</th>
      <th>weight</th>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>TO</th>
      <th>Consignor</th>              
      <th>Consignee</th>
      <th>Remark</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="selectedBilties" name="selectedBilties" value="11"></td>
      <td>gjhg</td>
      <td>ghj</td>
      <td>ghjg</td>
      <td>ghj</td>
      <td>ghjg</td>
      <td>ghj</td>
      <td>gjh</td>
      <td>ghj</td>
      <td>ghj</td>
      <td><input class="selected" type="text" id="freight_id" name="freight_id[]" value="val11"></td>
      <td><input class="selected" type="hidden" id="challan_id" name="challan_id[]" value="<?php echo $pod->challan_id; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="selectedBilties" name="selectedBilties" value="22"></td>
      <td>vbv</td>
      <td>gh</td>
      <td>gjh</td>
      <td>gh</td>
      <td>ghj</td>
      <td>ghj</td>
      <td>ghj</td>
      <td>ghj</td>
      <td>gjghj</td>
      <td><input class="selected" type="text" id="freight_id" name="freight_id[]" value="val22"></td>
      <td><input class="selected" type="hidden" id="challan_id" name="challan_id[]" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , how can I make these values like associate array or 2d array @Mamun

Comment: @KhanMuntazar, the answer is now in 2D array.....example of 2D array here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript